# Xamarin.Forms custom renderer for Android control from .axml layout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to figure out how to use an .axml layout file for a custom control in Xamarin.Forms.  Can anyone provide an example of using an .axml file in a custom renderer?  For example, I want to create a custom Entry control, (EnhancedEntry).  I want it to have configurable background and border colors as well as configurable border width.

I've created background shape,

```
drawable/enchancedEntryBackground.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
```

I have a layout defined in an .axml file thus,

```
layout/EnhancedEntry.axml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enhancedEntry"
        android:background="@drawable/enhancedentrybackground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Given a custom renderer skeleton and a class with properties to support the enhancements, is it possible to use the xml and axml specifications to create the new look?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EnhancedEntry), typeof(EnhancedEntryRenderer))]
namespace eSiteMobile.Droid.CustomRenderers
{

    public class EnhancedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);            
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }        
    }
}

public class EnhancedEntry : Entry
    {
        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color),
            typeof(EnhancedEntry), default(Color), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

        public static BindableProperty BorderWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderWidth), typeof(int),
            typeof(EnhancedEntry), default(int), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return (Color) GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public int BorderWidth
        {
            get { return (int) GetValue(BorderWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the properties you are talking about in `OnElementChanged()` referring to the rendered `Entry` as `Control`. It's not in axml or xml but its still possible.

Apparently in the Solution Explorer in VS you can click "Show All Files" and it will show the `Android.Resource.Layout` folder to add custom layout files. I say apparently because this did not work for me, but it is worth a try if you still are wanting to it in xml.

Once that is done you should be able to reference the layout file where you customized the View in the `OnElementChanged()` method but I find it easier to do it all in one place!